# How to force inline Scala self type declaration on code format

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, formatting

How can I configure Intellij IDEA code formatting in order to preserve inline [self type](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/self-types.html) declaration?

For instance, this:

```
trait ColumnTypeMappings { self: HasDatabaseConfigProvider[PostgresProfile] =>
//...
```

gets formatted as:

```
trait ColumnTypeMappings {
  self: HasDatabaseConfigProvider[PostgresProfile] =>
```

while I want to keep the former style.

I've taken a look at `Editor > Code Style > Scala`, but I can't find a suitable option :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try unchecking `Place self type on new line` under

```
Preferences | Editor | Code Style | Scala | Wrapping and Braces | Class Definition | Place self type on new line
```